# Get a List<Type> of all derived types in a list of objects that inherit from an abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I've seen a bunch of questions dealing with getting all types from a base type and so on, but that's not quite what I need. For instance, I have and abstract base class:

```
public abstract class BasePart
{
    //whatever 
}
```

And I have a bunch of classes that derive from it. Like...

```
public class HorizontalPanel : BasePart { //code }
public class VerticalPanel : BasePart { //code }
public class RainBoard : BasePart { //code }
```

And so on.
I always list them by the base class:

```
List<BasePart> parts;
```

And I use typecasting and generics to do whatever I want with them. However, I came to a point where I need to filter this list and I only want the **type information** available in it. And only once for type. For instance, if my list has three HorizontalPanels and two VerticalPanels, what I want from it is a `List<Type>` that only contains `{HorizontalPanel, VerticalPanel}`. I suppose I can mess around with the objects themselves in chained loops to get what I want, but I'm positive that C# has a better way to do it. Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no language feature to help you with this. The simplest way would be to use LINQ, first use `Select` to get all the types and use `Distinct`

```
parts.Select(x => x.GetType()).Distinct();
```

Comment: Fantastic, I had actually just thought of that, but the application isn't wired up to test it yet. I'll mark this as an answer as soon as I get to see it running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve the type of the object and populate a list.

Afterwards, since you need a list which contains only one instance of each type, you can call [`Enumerable.Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) on the list you populated previously, and [`Enumerable.ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to convert the resulting enumerable to a list.

All in all, the code will be something akin to:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Types>();

foreach (Base element in MyList){
    types.add(element.GetType());
};

List<Type> unique_types = types.Distinct().ToList();
```

Which will give you the list `unique_types` filled with exactly one instance of each type present in MyList.

Comment: Good all and all, but I'll go with the other answer. Thanks, anyway!